# GroupBy and get percentage for each

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my SQL table like this:

```
**CLIENTS:**
id
country
```

I want to echo a table with all countries I have with percentage fo each.

For example, if I have 2 Canadians and 1 French in my table, I want:

```
1 - Canada - 66%

2 - France - 33%
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT country FROM `mytable` GROUP BY `Country`;
```

It works, but how to have the percentage for each ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Having trouble with query that gets percentages using aggregate functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462400/sql-having-trouble-with-query-that-gets-percentages-using-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(id) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `mytable`) AS `something`
FROM
    `mytable`
GROUP BY
    `Country`;
```

Comment: Thanks. How for the second value (the percentage) I can ad an AS value ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a falvor of SQL, but years ago [microsoft posted their suggested solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256282/en-us):

```
select au_id
      ,(convert(numeric(5,2),count(title_id))
      /(Select convert(numeric(5,2),count(title_id)) from titleauthor)) * 100 
       AS "Percentage Of Total Titles"
 from titleauthor group by au_id
```

> To calculate the percentage of total records contained within a group
>   is a simple result that you can compute. Divide the number of records
>   aggregated in the group by the total number of records in the table,
>   and then multiply the result by 100. This is exactly what the
>   preceding query does. These points explain the query in greater
>   detail:
>
> 1. The inner nested query returns the total number of records in the
>      TitleAuthor table: [ Select convert(numeric(5,2),count(title_id)) from
>      titleauthor ]
> 2. The value returned by the COUNT(title_id) in the outer
>      GROUP BY query returns the number of titles written by a specific
>      author.
> 3. The value returned in step 2 is divided by the value returned
>      in step 1, and the result is multiplied by 100 to compute and display
>      the percentage of the total number of titles written by each author.
> 4. The nested SELECT is executed once for each row returned by the outer
>      GROUP BY query
> 5. The CONVERT function is used to cast the values
>      returned by the COUNT aggregate function to the numeric data type with
>      a precision of 5 and a scale of 3 to achieve the required level of
>      precision.